# SQL Server DATEPART for year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a call in SQL Server 2012 that I need to have working on Server 2005 and 2008.

`FORMAT(Date, 'yyyyMM') = 201501` is what I am currently using and need to use DATEPART older versions of SQL Server but cannot see a way of doing it easily.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: One way is convert(varchar(6), date, 112)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier versions of SQL Server don't have the `FORMAT`, so you'd need to so something like

```
YEAR(Date) = 2015 AND MONTH(Date) = 1
```

or something like that to check the two conditions

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this has worked perfectly for me.  The way the call is working its getting and information over the 12 month period so am calling this using this over 12 lines in the SQL call to get me the information i need.

Answer (score 1):

Should work with SQL Server 2005 and 2008

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT CAST(YEAR(@Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) 
       + RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(@Date) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)


RESULT:  201606
```

If you are going to use it in where clause you can do something like...

```
WHERE YEAR(DateColumn) = 2016
 AND  MONTH(DateColumn) = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to use DATEPART, this should work:

```
CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, CAST('2015-01-05' AS DATETIME)) AS VARCHAR(4))
    +RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(MM, CAST('2015-01-05' AS DATETIME)) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
```

Alternatively, you could use YEAR or MONTH like the other posts suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to do it.

```
SELECT YEAR(GETDATE())*100 + MONTH(GETDATE())
```